# Enable hideshow for more modes, e.g. Ruby?

Tags: emacs, code-folding

[hideshow](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) is cool, but it's limited to only a few programming languages. Can someone help me add support for more, such as Ruby and Haskell?

Comment: The emacs wiki page you linked to has some suggestions. Look at the [Universal code folding](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow#toc5) section. Try some of the suggestions out and report back with ay specific problems.

Comment: @terdon Yes, I'm looking at this page and I have no idea how to apply it. I'd like to use indentation-based folding, with hideshowvis, for all modes.

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda () (hs-minor-mode)))

(eval-after-load "hideshow"
  '(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
              `(ruby-mode
                ,(rx (or "def" "class" "module" "do" "{" "[" "if" "else" "unless")) ; Block start
                ,(rx (or "}" "]" "end"))                       ; Block end
                ,(rx (or "#" "=begin"))                        ; Comment start
                ruby-forward-sexp nil)))
```

Found it here https://coderwall.com/p/u-l0ra/ruby-code-folding-in-emacs